# What is the primary purpose of function expression in Module Pattern

Tags: javascript

I know that Module Pattern is very useful and powerful in Javascript programming.
I recognized that pattern in [Eric Miraglia's blog](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) for the first time , but I am wondering one thing.
In other blogs and articles that explain Module Pattern, I notice that their sample codes are slightly different from Eric's article, that is, they use function expression with parenthesis rather than function statement, for example, [the article from ben cherry](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) is one of them.

Is there any specific reason to use function expression rather than function statement?
Please explain with easy way, I just entered into Javascript Programming world :)

Answer (score 2):

The Miraglia pattern is the same, defining an anonymous function and executing it.  The difference is that in order to *use* the features of the module, you must have a reference to an instance somewhere.  Assigning the module to a global variable (YAHOO.*) is a way to retain the reference at a globally known spot, especially important for frameworks (like YUI).

Sometimes you don't need that reference.  For example, if you are writing JavaScript for a web page, you often bind events to functions using selectors (ids / types, etc.)  That really removes the need for any global reference to your module function.

Hope that make sense...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve, I think my question is somewhat short to describe my idea, let'me simply ask a question again. what is the difference between following two codes? First, var b = (function () { doSomething... }());   Second, var b = function(){ doSomething... }();    First one is function expression and second one is function statement as long as I know. In Eric's article he used second way and in most other articles, they use first way.

Comment: The expressions are the same.  The first one only has an extra pair of parentheses around it, which are superfluous.